# unable Setting mysql wait_timeout variable value

Tags: mysql, linux

I am trying to set the MYSql environment variable wait_timeout.When I am doing through the mysql prompt using

mysql>set wait_timeout =10;

it gets reflected in the current prompt only and is not reflected globally(from the outside of the current prompt).
I also tried to set it from the outside the mysql prompt using command:

set wait_timeout=10;

but again this didnot worked for me.
I am using Debian(Linux),Please tell me how I can the Wait_timeout so that it would get reflected globally in mysql server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try setting it in /etc/my.cnf?

See [this link](http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/mysql_intro.html#SECTION0001500000) for more info.  [Here's a "non-bug"](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=33123) that explores that setting that might be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Please use this command "set global wait_timeout =10". It will work.